# Запуск нескольких приложений в Linux на разных поддоменах

Tags: linux, nginx

Я тут сейчас постигаю азы работы с Linux. Задача тривиальная - задеплоить и запустить .Net Core приложение. С помощью [оффдокументации](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/linux-nginx?view=aspnetcore-3.1) понял суть и в принципе все у меня получилось. Сейчас приложение запускается на поддомене `panel.my-domain.com`, но яхочу пойти немного дальше, запустить второе приложение на другом поддомене к примеру `me.my-domain.com`. Тут у меня затык не имею понятия как сконфигурировать проксисервер(Nginix) чтоб на второй субдомен отображал приложение 2.
Я сделал так:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name panel.my-domain.com;
        root /home/ftpuser/ftp/files/apps/App_1;
        location / {
                proxy_pass         http://localhost:6000;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header   Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header   Connection keep-alive;
                proxy_set_header   Host $host;
                proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        }
}
server {
        listen 81;
        server_name me.my-domain.com;
        root /home/ftpuser/ftp/files/apps/App_2;
        location / {
                proxy_pass         http://localhost:5000;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header   Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header   Connection keep-alive;
                proxy_set_header   Host $host;
                proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        }
}
```

но в итоге на обеих поддоменах отображается первое приложение.
Подскажите как это правильно сделать.

Comment: Во втором блоке тоже должно быть `listen 80;`

Comment: И nginx ни разу не прокси-сервер. Это веб-сервер который умеет работать как [обратный прокси](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B8)

Comment: А вы обратили внимание что в конфиге у вас порт для второго приложения `81`? Скорее всего он отрабатывает по настройкам `defaul`, вот вы и не видите результата. Ну и перегружать настройки `nginx -t && nginx -s reload` тоже необходимо.